# Convert Degree Coordinates to Decimal

Tags: linux, bash, unix, coordinates

I have two text files that contain the following lat/lon (degree) coordinates:

**Lats:**

```
161N
168N
174N
182N
190N
198N
203N
207N
210N
213N
216N
220N
222N
224N
```

**Lons:**

```
609W
636W
663W
692W
720W
747W
768W
790W
808W
827W
845W
865W
882W
899W
```

I need to get these degree coordinates to decimal formats.

Ex:

`161N` > `16.1N`
`609W` > `-60.9W`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed

```
sed "s/\([0-9][ENSW]\)$/.\1/" file.txt
```

This uses a regular expression to group the last digit in the string with the last letter that is an E, N, S or W and inserts a period before them.

Comment: An explanation of what is happening will help the OP (and others) understand `sed` and your answer…

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the desired result with:

```
sed -i 's/.$//' ${model}_lats_tmp
sed -i 's/.$//' ${model}_lons_tmp

awk '{print $1/10}' ${model}_lats_tmp > ${model}_lats_new
awk '{print $1/10}' ${model}_lons_tmp > ${model}_lons_new
```